# How can I check request day with php?

Tags: php, time, timer

For example: x user booking ticket on monday and ticket status changing as book. After three days, ticket status will change as free(empty) automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to be more precise. Also, what did you try ?

Comment: You need to use a cron job that runs every day, running a script that updates the database.

Comment: I must run code on localhost. Can I do this on localhost (win7)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)):

```
if ($ticket_timestamp < strtotime("-3 days")) {
  // ticket is expired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will usually want to check this by date. If you don't care about the actual date but just need to compare, you can use the time() function. The day is time()/60/60/24 .

You can store the timestamp of the order in the database and then compare it with the current time.

Comment: Yes I want to do this also. When user booking a ticket, saving current time,user info,ticket info etc. How can I check time when it change?